# TypeError: http.ServerResponse is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

I've been building my React app (using create-react-app) and suddenly I have hit the following error:
TypeError: http.ServerResponse is undefined

I was in the process of adding a delete comment functionality that sends off a delete request using axios, if that makes a difference.

I'm new to React and have no idea what to do, now. ***How do I debug this?***

Help very much appreciated!

I'm using axios if that helps, node backend and react.

Comment: can you Provide some screenshots ?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for your answer - this saved me a lot of time. I had a very similar situation with the same error message but in Vue.JS, after moving

```
axios.post(...).then(response => {...}).catch();
```

via copy+paste from a component to Vuex store file, VSCode added `import { response } from 'express';` to the top of my store file causing this error and App crash. **So watch out for express imports!**

Comment: 100% same issue here! This saved me hours of trying to find the issue!

Answer (score 5):

somehow vscode provided an auto import "e from 'express'" which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The imports have an random
import e from "express";
at the top! At least this is my fix.