# Uncaught TypeError: u.ServerResponse is undefined in console when connecting to my netlify website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I just want to know where this error is coming from.  I have the frontend hosted here: https://anonsanonymous.netlify.app/ with the repository located here: https://github.com/JohnTarvis/a2frontend

The backend is hosted here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/damp-island-15072 and its repository is here: https://github.com/JohnTarvis/a2backend

When I try to connect I get this in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: u.ServerResponse is undefined
    <anonymous> Express
    <anonymous> 2.36dea072.chunk.js:2
    l (index):1
    <anonymous> Express
    l (index):1
    <anonymous> Express
    l (index):1
    454 main.680672dd.chunk.js:1
    l (index):1
    213 main.680672dd.chunk.js:1
    l (index):1
    t (index):1
    r (index):1
    <anonymous> main.680672dd.chunk.js:1
```

I've tried rebuilding the build folder, reinstalling the package.json files and commenting some of the imports to try to narrow down the source.  Next I'll try to comment all the imports just to see if I get a different error.  I'm not sure where those chunk files are being generated.  All I did was attempt to add functionality to let users upload images using S3.

I found a similar post here: [TypeError: http.ServerResponse is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794128/typeerror-http-serverresponse-is-undefined) and did what was suggested but to no avail.

Right now, I just want to get an idea of where this is coming from.  Is it the frontend, backend or netlify itself?  I've just started in web development so forgive me if I've missed something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had 'express' imported one too many times.